# Storing temporary downloaded data in Android application

Tags: java, android, rest, design-patterns, android-fragments

I have a couple of applications that display downloaded content.
So, data is get in XML via REST, and then parsed to `ArrayList<MY_MODEL_CLASS>`.
Applications consist of `ViewPager`s with Fragments, they also have nested Fragments. Data is loaded when user opens corresponding fragments.

Currently all ArrayLists are usual class fields inside Fragments(`private ArrayList<Event> downloadedEvents;`). To prevent data loss and re-downloading after orientation change, fragments are set to `setRetainInstance(true);`. But child fragments doesn't allow to do that, so data is getting lost and re-downloaded.

Of course, I can save instance state, save ArrayList to Bundle as Parcelable, make ArrayList static, etc.

---

My **question** is more theoretic, that practic: I would like to know *good practices of holding downloaded data* inside application while it's running **without** writing it to persistent memory as SQLite.

---

My variants are:

- Store data in fragments, which display corresponding data, and save instance state to preserve ArrayList between orientation change.
- Store data in fragments, but just make fields static to preserve between object re-creation.
- Make one singleton object that stores all data for all fragments.

But I suppose, that none of them is really good.

What solutions (patterns) do professionals use?
Thanks! :)

Comment: IMO if it's specific to the fragment keep it in the saved instance state, if it's shared among among fragments or other things a singleton pattern works well. The benefit of a singleton pattern is you can update/refresh it and the changes can be displayed more easily than if you have to pass the data in your other solutions. You just need to watch out for concurrency issues if you have multiple threads working on it.

Comment: @DaveS Data is always specific to a single fragment. But IMO as of fragments being recreated on small changes like orientation change, they may be not appropriate for holding important (downloaded) data. Am I right?

Comment: The use case you describe seems to be exactly what the saved instance state was designed for.